# Are there any four-armed creatures in any pantheon?

Tags: mythical-creatures, pantheon

Related to my [last question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/are-there-any-four-armed-deities-or-creatures-in-the-greek-or-roman-pantheons): Are there any races/species of creature in *any* pantheon with four arms (and two legs and one head)?

Comment: What is the difference with your previous question actually?

Comment: @plannapus The widening of the acceptable source pantheon. For example, Norse mythology has a serpent around the equator; Greco-Roman mythology does not. So if there was *one* example in the Greco-Roman pantheon, there might be more examples in other belief systems.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum ah indeed, didn't understood the first one excluded other pantheons, my bad.

Comment: It's been a while since I read the Chinese *[Classic of Mountains and Seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Mountains_and_Seas)*, so I can't remember if this configuration appears specifically, but I wouldn't be surprised, since the book is mytho/combinatorial.

Comment: http://pbfcomics.com/comics/spelling/ shows a four-handed elephant god, but it might be from a modern fictional mythology that is off-topic per https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/143/197 .

Answer (score 6):

Such creatures are easily spotted in Indian depictions from various times. Ganesha, Lakshmi and Vishnu are probably the most popular, and there is a  book on the topic which might be useful:  Doris Srinivasan *Many Heads, Arms and eyes: Origin, Meaning and Forms of Multiplicity in Indian Art* (Brill, 1997).

Comment: You know the drill by now: Some quotes or paraphrases from your source would improve this answer.

Comment: It is my understanding the Indian/Vedic gods are usually portrayed or described with multiple arms, but the number often changes from one depiction to another (or from avatar to avatar). And, technically, I excluded deities in the question by specifying races and creatures.

Comment: In a *pantheon*, the word suggests it, the creatures are deities.